# Pagebale & sort by COUNT() with other table - JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I've got this query

```
SELECT t.id,t.title,count(k.id) as likes
FROM topics t
LEFT JOIN topic_like k on t.id = k.topic_id
group by t.id, t.title
ORDER BY likes desc ;
```

When I try to convert it to the JPQL, I do it like this but I gut some issues

```
@Query("SELECT p,count(k.id) as likes FROM TopicJpa p " +
            "LEFT JOIN TopicLikeJpa k " +
            "GROUP BY p ORDER BY COUNT(likes)")
    Page<TopicJpa> getAllTopicsWithLikeCountsSort(Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should be:

```
SELECT p, count(k) as likes
FROM TopicJpa p
         LEFT JOIN p.topicLikeJpa k
GROUP BY p
ORDER BY likes
```

You can return the result as a `Page<Object[]>`:

```
@Query("...")
Page<Object[]> getAllTopicsWithLikeCountsSort(Pageable pageable);
```

```
Page<Object[]> page = repository.getAllTopicsWithLikeCountsSort(...);
List<Object[]> resultList = page.getContent();
for(Object[] row : resultList) {
   TopicJpa topic = (TopicJpa) row[0];
   Long counter = (Long) row[1];
}
```

Or, you can create an interface with two fields:

```
interface TopicWithCounter {
    TopicJpa getTopic();
    Long getLikes();
}
```

and use it as the page type:

```
@Query("...")
Page<TopicWithCounter> getAllTopicsWithLikeCountsSort(Pageable pageable);
```

If you don't care about the count for each topic, you can omit it from the select clause and return `Page<TopicJpa>` instead:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM TopicJpa p LEFT JOIN p.topicLikeJpa k GROUP BY p ORDER BY COUNT(k)")
Page<TopicJpa> getAllTopicsWithLikeCountsSort(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: but what about the return object data type! , I think count(k) should not be there!

Comment: Although... I'm not sure the approach with the interface dto will work. I haven't tested it.

Comment: with the return of List<Object[]> will work, but I need some properties of  Pageable, Do I need to do it manually!

Comment: If you only need `TopicJpa` and you don't care about the count, you can remove it from the select clause: ```from TopicJpa p left join p.topicLikeJpa k group by p order by count(k) ```. This query will return a `List<TopicJpa>`. I don't know what's the issue with pagination.

Comment: Ah... I think you can return a `Page<Object[]>`

Comment: There was an error in my answer... let me fix it

Comment: Ok, now my answer should cover all cases... good luck.

Comment: It's doesn't work :(

Comment: Yeah... well... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: May I send u a google meet that may be will be better to explain the problem?  :\

Comment: No, thanks. I've already enough meetings :) SO is a better place to learn how to explain a problem. You can start by saying what doesn't work.

Comment: hahaha, I'll try to solve it by myself, if I got no way I will explain the problem to you :) . I Appreciate your help

Comment: I've tested all three solutions and there were a couple of minor details wrong: `coun(k)` will return a `Long` not an `Integer`, and you need to add the select clause in the last query. Other than that they all work as expected. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Is there any why to add the Order by at here PageRequest.of(offset,pageSize, Sort.by(direction,"<<HERE?!>>")

Comment: What do you mean? There's nothing special to do: ```getAllTopicsWithLikeCountsSort( PageRequest.of( 0, 2, Sort.by( ASC, "likes" ) ) )```

Comment: But you have to remove the `order by` from the HQL query

Comment: I do like this  
 @Query("SELECT NEW PATH...TopicDto(p.id,p.title,COUNT(k))" +
            "FROM TopicJpa p " +
            "LEFT JOIN p.topicLikeJpa k " +
            "GROUP BY p.id,p.title")
    Page<TopicDto> getAllTopicsWithAllFilter(Pageable pageable);

--------------
topicRepository.getAllTopicsWithAllFilter(PageRequest.of(offset,pageSize, Sort.by(ASC,"topicLikeJpa.size"))

And I think it works fine, is there any way to add (As likes)

Comment: You don't have to call `select new TopicDTO( ... )`. Just declare it as an interface like I showed you in the answer and it will work. Please, don't add any more comments to this answer. That's not how SO works.